# What is the right way to make a post call in Angular 9 to pass a file to express-fileupload?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, postman

i'm able to do that in postman like that 
[image: postman call working perfectly]

But in Angular is not working, this is the Angular code js:

```
<input type="file" #fileUpload id="fileUpload" name="file" multiple="multiple" accept=".csv"  />
const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    this.caricautentiService.caricautenti(this.globals.idPersona,formData).subscribe( response => { 
        console.log(response);
    });
```

this is the service:

```
    if (file !== undefined) {
        formParams = formParams.append('file', <any>file) as any || formParams;

    }

    return this.httpClient.request<any>('post',`${this.basePath}/caricautenti/${encodeURIComponent(String(idpersona))}`,
        {
            body: formParams,
            withCredentials: this.configuration.withCredentials,
            headers: headers,
            observe: observe,
            reportProgress: reportProgress
        }
    );
```

What am i missing?
Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```js
public addFileToProgram(file: any): Observable<any> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    return this.http.post<any>('/v1/uploadfile', formData);
}
```